# Google Maps multiple pins via query striing

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps, query-string

If I generate a link like so:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/?q=14,15&14z
```

the link will take me to a position on earth, and have a pin in the middle.

If I use the following link:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/?ll=14,15&14z
```

It would take me to the same position but without the pin in the middle.

**QUESTION:** Is there a way to generate a link that would take you to a location, and have various pins placed in different locations (without necessarily being in the middle like in the case above for instance) and have all those specifications done in the query string?

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported to provide multiple pins via query string. Instead you could create [My Maps using Google Maps](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3045850?guide=21670&rd=2) containing multiple markers and then share the URL.

[Example: link to My Map](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1T3L9pEgZoJ7g_VKzCfNoBgodFFE&usp=sharing)